# Rally: Date User Story is Defined

Tags: date, rally, defined, user-stories

I am writing a program that needs to fetch user stories that are defined before day 3 of a release. Is there a way to find out what day a user story was set to the 'defined' state so that I could query that?

I looked through the Web Service API docs but I couldn't find anything that could help me, although I could have missed something.

This is the code I am using to get the 3rd day of a release:

`var releaseStart = combobox.getRecord().get('ReleaseStartDate');
    releaseStart.setDate(releaseStart.getDate()+3);
    this._startDate = Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(releaseStart);`

But I'm not sure how to relate this to the date a user story is defined.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're right- this piece of data does not exist in the standard WSAPI.  You can get it from LookbackAPI however.  How about something like this to get started?

```
var releaseStart = combobox.getRecord().get('ReleaseStartDate');
var startDate = Rally.util.DateTime.add(releaseStart, 'day', 3);
var snapshotStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
    context: {
        workspace: this.getContext().getWorkspaceRef()
    },
    find: {
        _ProjectHierarchy: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID,
        _TypeHierarchy: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
        ScheduleState: {$gte: 'Defined'},
        __At: startDate
    },
    sort: {
        _UnformattedID: 1
    },
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState'],
    limit: Infinity,
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            //TODO: work with records here
        }
    }
});
```

More information on working with the Lookback API is here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/lookback_api

Comment: I am actually not familiar with it at all. I'm very new to developing for Rally.

Comment: ok, let me try to whip up something for you to get started with.  here's what we'll be using: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/lookback_api

Comment: Okay! That looks like something that could help

Comment: I updated the answer above with some code.  Try it out and see how that goes for you!